# Is there anything in SWTOR that you can't buy with cartel coins?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm debating on whether or not to get a subscription or cartel coins my personal thought is that I can get all the things I need with cartel coins and they won't expire. Is there anything that I can only get through subscription?

Comment: Operations passes and the like are for a single week.  And to maintain them constantly costs more than a sub, though of course you can buy them from other players with credits.  Artifact gear authorization, crew skill slots, etc. are permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full breakdown of privileges for subscription vs. preferred status vs. free to play is on [swtor.com](http://www.swtor.com/free/features).

Most restrictions can be bypassed with cartel coins to access otherwise unavailable items (e.g. purple quality items) but preferred status and free to play players have a credit cap which prevents you from purchasing items that sell for higher than the credit cap. For the same reason, some [mission rewards are not accessible](http://www.swtor.com/support/helpcenter/6820) to preferred status and free to play players.